# AS3 : What is the context of 'this' in an anonymous function?

Tags: actionscript-3, this, anonymous-function

In this example:

```
    public function Roulette() {
        new QuickLoad(url, function (o:*):void {trace(this);});
    }
```

when **QuickLoad** instance does its stuff, it calls the anonymous function. One would think that ***this*** is **Roulette**. But no, it turns out to be the anonymous function's caller, which is **QuickLoad**.

This is weird to say the least, say how am I supposed to pass the "correct" ***this*** (i.e. **Roulette** instance) inside the anonymous function if I don't do it **the normal way?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save the outer `this` instance under a different name so that it is preserved:

```
public function Roulette() {
    var rouletteThis = this;
    new QuickLoad(url, function (o:*):void {trace(rouletteThis);});
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is quite what he was asking for, though it is useful to the purpose, I'm sure. How do you get `this` to refer to the `Roulette()` function, not to the `QuickLoad` object.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to call a function with an alternate `this` pointer, but since your function is called from within `new QuickLoad()`, you need to alter *that* call statement, and pass your `this` as Roulette into the constructor. Your new `QuickLoad` object is unaware of its surroundings, and even the caller of the constructor is unknown to it. Thus, you need to make it aware, pass a `this` pointer from `Roulette()` to `QuickLoad()`, AND call the function from `QuickLoad` with passing an alternate `this` pointer.

```
public function QuickLoad(url:String,caller:Object=null,callback:Function=null) {
    // initialization code
    if (callback!=null) {
        if (caller!=null) callback.apply(caller,[o]);
        else callback.apply(this,[o]);
    }
}
...
public function Roulette() {
    new QuickLoad(url, this, function (o:*):void {trace(this);});
}
```

[Function::apply() manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html#apply%28%29).

You can also use `call()` method, if your argument array has fixed length. `callback.call(caller,o);`

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in this context, `this` refers to an object. To quote a rather infamous acronym: INABIAF (It's not a bug, it's a feature), LOL. So, yes, the object instance QuickLoad that is calling the function is going to be what `this` looks at by default.

There is an exception I know of (out of many, I'm sure)...you can get anything...variable, function, object, whatever, via this["Name of Object"]. But that's an aside.

There ARE other workarounds, I'm sure, which may or may not be practical for your purposes. This is one way of passing a function, out of many, and it's the one I use the most.

Functions do not have instances. They're not objects. If you want to send a function as an argument to another function, you simply pass it, as follows in this rather weird example.

```
//This function accepts a function as an argument.
function bridgeOfQuestions(person:String, response:Function):void
{
    if(person == "King Arthur")
    {
        response("What is the average airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?");
    }
    else
    {
        response("What is your favorite color?");
    }
}

//This is the function we're going to pass.
function askQuestion(question:String):void
{
    trace(question);
}

//Here, we call bridgeOfQuestions and pass it the askQuestion function.
//NOTE: Leave off the parenthesis on the function being passed!
bridgeOfQuestions("Sir Lancelot", askQuestion);
bridgeOfQuestions("King Arthur", askQuestion);
```

EDIT: If it is just the *name* you're passing, a function is a function permanently. It doesn't change, unlike an object, and as I said, it doesn't have instances. Therefore, if you merely want to print out the name of the function, you'd only use `trace("Roulette")`.